# SDL Tridion : How do I schedule a page to publish recurrently?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have to schedule a page to publish automatically once a week. I don't see any out if the box feature to schedule it.  How can this be achieved using the SDL Tridion 2011 APIs.

Comment: Hi user1729917 - Thanks for posting your first SDL Tridion question on SO - If you are active in the Tridion community, please consider committing to the Area51 proposal using your Stack Overflow User ID at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet would be to write a small command line or power shell script which uses the SDL Tridion Core Service, then schedule it to run using the Windows Task Scheduler. Once you have created a Core Service client ([there are lots of examples here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tridion%20core%20service)), you can then call the publish method as follows:

```
_client.Publish(pageId, publishInstruction, targets, priority, readOptions);
```

If you need further details please download the CoreService API from the following URL and search for "ICoreService2011.Publish":

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2011SP1/index.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response Chris.It was really helpful. I will start looking into it.

Comment: If you found this useful - please consider using the voting buttons and joining Area51